# Creating an item with the API returns 201, but then I cannot find the item?

Tags: sitecore-api

Note: I am using a trial instance of Sitecore 9.0.2.

I create an item:

```
curl -X POST \
 https://mysitecoreurl/sitecore/api/ssc/item/%2Fsitecore%2Fcontent%2FHome%2Ffolder1 \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{ 
    "ItemName": "Home4", 
    "TemplateID": "76036f5e-cbce-46d1-af0a-4143f9b557aa", 
    "Title": "Sitecore2", 
    "Text": "\r\n\t\t<p>Welcome to Sitecore 4</p>\r\n" 
}'
```

It returns seems ok?

```
Status: 201 Created
Location: Location →https://mysitecoreurl/sitecore/api/ssc/item/b8527e6a-f731-4cb2-a8a0-1f3cd8d7bd4f?Database=master
```

So I get the GUID of the folder:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://mysitecoreurl/sitecore/api/ssc/item/?path=/sitecore/content/Home/folder1'
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "ItemID": "fe2e79b2-2b0c-4866-a6b4-70eab694e58b",
    "ItemName": "folder1",
    "ItemPath": "/sitecore/content/Home/folder1",
    "ParentID": "110d559f-dea5-42ea-9c1c-8a5df7e70ef9",
    "TemplateID": "a87a00b1-e6db-45ab-8b54-636fec3b5523",
    "TemplateName": "Folder",
    "CloneSource": null,
    "ItemLanguage": "en",
    "ItemVersion": "1",
    "DisplayName": "folder1",
    "HasChildren": "True",
    "ItemIcon": "/temp/iconcache/applications/16x16/folder.png",
    "ItemMedialUrl": "/temp/iconcache/applications/48x48/folder.png",
    "ItemUrl": "~/link.aspx?_id=FE2E79B22B0C4866A6B470EAB694E58B&amp;_z=z"
}
```

Now when I try to get the children of the folder:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://mysitecoreurl/sitecore/api/ssc/item/fe2e79b2-2b0c-4866-a6b4-70eab694e58b/children
```

I do not see my new item.

```
curl -X GET \
  https://mysitecoreurl/sitecore/api/ssc/item/b8527e6a-f731-4cb2-a8a0-1f3cd8d7bd4f
```

Returns:

```
The item "b8527e6a-f731-4cb2-a8a0-1f3cd8d7bd4f" was not found.

It may have been deleted by another user.
```

Am I missing something?

But here it is in the UI: [image: yet here it is]

and the guid of that item matches: [image]

What am I missing here?

I have a feeling I'm missing some sort of "Publish" step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because you are missing the database param in your request for your item?

The default is the context database for the logged in user so perhaps you are logged into Core or Web?:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://mysitecoreurl/sitecore/api/ssc/item/b8527e6a-f731-4cb2-a8a0-1f3cd8d7bd4f?Database=master
```

Comment: I just ran `{{sitecoreURL}}/sitecore/api/ssc/item/fe2e79b2-2b0c-4866-a6b4-70eab694e58b/children?Database=master` that just times out. never returns anything

Comment: yep that's because now it's so big, there's no way it can return that number of results in one query.

Comment: What is so big? I single item can’t be that big surely? Or are you returning the child items for that item also?

Comment: yeah it was the "children" call which was lots of possibly large items

Comment: Ok well I’d delete your children in the UI and then test the call above

Comment: yes that definitely worked. so how does that whole thing work? so you can have a path say `/sitecore/content/Home/folder1` that can contain files from multiple different databases? Why is that?

Comment: The API just follows the standard Sitecore publishing model of items not published being in the master database and then published items being in the web database. If you want to find unpublished items use master or if they are published and you are using the API for publicly shown item details then you need to use web in your request.

Comment: ahhhh now i understand. sorry, sitecore noob here.

Comment: No worries. Glad it makes sense. Also the recommended practice is a Max of a couple of hundred child items below an item as Sitecore's UI and other queries can perform slowly otherwise. Id suggest using item buckets instead, more info here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/managing_items/item_buckets/item_buckets

Comment: Created a followup question you might be able to help me with: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14231/are-content-buckets-able-to-be-fetched-using-the-item-service-api